Printers offline after Printer Spooler service restarted
i have a windows 7, the os version is  6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601.
I have a cups server that shares multiple printers to my windows 7.
I  create printers on windows 7 with command like this :
 rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b HP-Test-Printer /r "http://192.168.123.18:631/printers/HP-Test-Printer" /m "HP Universal Printing PS"

when printers are created, all printers are online, but if restart Print Spooler service, all printers are offline.
did i do something wrong ?
Thanks much!
